# Misunderstanding an if statement in a for loop

Tags: r, if-statement, for-loop, levels

I am relatively new to R and I can not figure out a way of making my code work. I have a dataset with all the municipalities of the Netherlands and I want to print only the municipalities that are in my list named b. If I select a number inside my dataframe by using df[i] it also contains levels. Would it work without the levels?

df contains all municipality names of the Netherlands and
b is a list of reshaped municipalities

```
df <- mun_neth$GM_NAAM
b <- list(gem_her$Nieuwe.gemeente)
for(i in df){
  a <- df[i]
  if(a in b){
     print(a)
}}
```

Comment: There are several things wrong with your code. Do you possibly want `mun_neth$GM_NAAM[mun_neth$GM_NAAM %in% gem_her$Nieuwe.gemeente]`?

Comment: As a general rule: people who closed, please comment as to why this is unclear, so the author has a chance to edit his question. Obviously, not everyone thought this was unclear. IMHO, the question, answer, and comments do draw a pretty clear picture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct syntax would be (read each line carefully and compare with yours.)

```
df <- mun_neth$GM_NAAM
b <- gem_her$Nieuwe.gemeente
for(a in df){
  if(a %in% b){
     print(a)
}}
```

But look at `intersect` so you can do the work of the whole loop in a single call:

```
intersect(df, b)
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reactions. Intersect works and what Roland put in the comment works to. But the for loop does not work, actually this was also something I tried before. And because of later additions I want to iterate through the municipalities, so stay in the for loop. So thank you very much it is already really helpfull, but are there further suggestions?

Comment: If you have factors, try to wrap `a` and/or `b` inside `as.character()`.

Comment: wait, why is `b` a list and not a vector? Try to do `b <- gem_her$Nieuwe.gemeente`. I have edited my answer.

Comment: @Zuenie, glad to help. If this solved your problem, please consider accepting the answer by clicking the tick mark to the left.